# print directory using command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Found this one: http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-print-a-directory-tree-from-windows-explorer.html

But I don't know how do I do it and save the directory listing somewhere.
What I want to do is something like that, but I need an output file.
Or at least something that I can see.
What I need to do is to print the contents of a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir > dir_contents.txt
print dir_contents.txt
```

in short. You pipe it to the file of your choice, using dir options of your choice.

Edit:
If print doesn't work you can try this instead

```
start /w notepad /p dir_contents.txt
```

It uses notepad to print the file to your default printer.

Comment: is the print command supported out of the box these days? It does not work on my win7

Comment: Sorry, have no idea. Still not using them (so someone else will have to answer that one). But anyways, you can always print that file in a number of ways (including the one from explorer as mentioned in the article).

Comment: @Nifle - that's one way for example, yes. Thanks for adding that.

Comment: @Nifle & Idigas- Is it possible to customize it so that the output(dir_contents.txt) will only show the file name and the file type.

Comment: @Nrew - you mean, customize what dir outputs ? To show only the name+extension ? Yeah, sure. How about this: "dir /b /og" - will show directories at top, then the files (you just place this instead of "dir" above in the answer; nothing else changes)

Answer (score 2):

Change `"%temp%\Listing"` to the location and filename that you want to use.

Don't include the `del` line, which deletes the file created.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196158
go to this link and it will show you exactly how to do it I used this in Win 7 and it works.